# How to check whether sql query returning a value or not?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query. Just i want to check query returning a values or not using c#. Can any one help on this to fix it. Thanks in advance.

```
Sqlcommand cmd = new Sqlcomman("select Name from Engdetails",con)

if (query != 0)
{
  some coding..
}
else
{
  coding...
}
```

Comment: It mut be a non copy paste mistake, but you forgot a 'd' on SqlCommand

Comment: And a semicolon at the end.

Comment: And `SqlCommand` needs to be capitalized. And `query` came out of nowhere. What does `query != 0` represent? The number of rows returned? The question needs some fixing up.

Comment: thank u so much guys. i really appriciate for your quick response.

Answer (score 4):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Name from Engdetails",con)

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.Read())
{
   // The command returns Row(s)
}
else
{
   // No Row has been returned.
}
```

Comment: thank u so much guys. i really appriciate for your quick response.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to work with sqlCommand; some examples:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
  if (reader.HasRows)
  {
    reader.Read();
...
```

or

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
{
   using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
   {
      adapter.Fill(data);
   }
```

if it has data, the data will be in data.Tables

Comment: `reader.HasRows` is redundant. `Read()` will return `true` or `false depending on if there was a row available or not.

Comment: .HasRows will return whether or not there are any rows to read without moving the read pointer, which .Read() will do.  I'll grant you that normally reader.Read() would be in a while loop, but .HasRows answers the posters question.

Comment: Execpt that you unconditionally call `reader.Read()` the first line of the `if` statement. I am saying replace `if(reader.HasRows) { reader.Read()` with `if(reader.Read())`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Name from Engdetails", con);
int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (i > 0)
{
    // somecoding
}
else
{
    // somecoding
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a example in this case rdr.GetString is Name value of the query.

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constr))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        MySqlDataReader rdr = null;


        string[] dados_bd = new string[2];

        conn.Open();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = sql;

        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
            {
                if (estado == 1)
                {

                    dados_bd[0] = rdr.GetString(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
For the UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the SQL statement.

For all other types of statements, the return value is -1.